# How run a stored procedure present in SQL Developer from a Control-M database job with Execution type as embedded query

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, control-m

I am new to Control-M scheduling and the scenario I have at hand is like below:

There is a stored procedure in SQL DEVELOPER which creates subpartition queries on a table. Now I need to schedule a Control-M job which runs this stored procedure directly into the database and schema mentioned in the controlM job parameters. I was able to set up the database connection part and with the Execution type as embedded query I wrote the SQL statement:    **EXEC <procedure_name>;**

The Control-M job is failing with ORA00900: invalid SQL statement.

Note: the procedure doesnot have any partition. Also when I run the same query in SQL developer it runs successfully giving the expected result. The issue is with execution from Control-M job.

Can anyone please help with the solution. Many thanks!

Comment: The procedure is stored in the database, not in desktop tools such as SQL Developer. I don't know Control-M but I doubt that it provides an `exec` command. If you have documentation for the product it should be easy to confirm this. The SQL equivalent is `call`, or if it supports PL/SQL anonymous blocks, `begin ... end;`.

Comment: What is control-M? Do a begin proc(a=>1..); end; vs a exec, which is a SQLPlus cmd

Comment: @thatjeffsmith it's a job scheduler. https://www.bmc.com/it-solutions/control-m.html

Answer (score 0):

@thatjeffsmith Control-M is the market leading job scheduling solution, it exists in Distributed (Unix and Windows and everything else) versions and Mainframe (with the possibility to skip between the 2).

Control-M can run scripts or commands. You won't be able to run a stored proc straight from a system command prompt but they have a solution for this. Control-M has many modules that run under the Control-M Agent (the Agent is installed locally on the box where you want to execute stuff) and these Agents come in many different varieties; ones manage file transfers, one to run SAP jobs, Oracle applications, Hadoop, all sorts of things.

The one you need is **Control-M for Databases**. Install that under your Control-M Agent (it's free for existing customers), takes 2 mins to add and it works with all the major DB vendors. Once running, setup a connection profile(s) on the Control-M for Databases module (DB name, id, pw, port number, the usual).

Then (back on your Control-M system) create a Control-M for Databases job. You can either choose a stored proc or use Control-M to store your SQL or whatever. Control-M gives you features like variables (including saving your output as a variable), rerun options, dependencies on other jobs, notifications (e.g. for failures or late runners), workload balancing, version control, yadda-yadda-yadda ...

Answer (score 0):

I was able to run the stored procedure with the execution type as stored procedure in Control-M. Earlier I was not able to do this because of database connectivity issue, when that was solved I was able to do it.

Thanks!